# How to prove $|a|-|b| \le ||a|-|b||$.

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

I can't figure out how to prove this. Intuitively, it seems to be true but I still want to see how one can prove this.

Comment: In general we have $x\leq\max\{x,-x\}=|x|$. Now put $x=|a|-|b|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $c=|a|-|b|$ is just some real number.  For any real number $c$, $c\leq |c|$: if $c\geq 0$ then $c=|c|$, and if $c<0$ then $|c|>0$ so $|c|>c$.  Your inequality is then just $c\leq |c|$ in the case $c=|a|-|b|$.

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you so much. I feel so stupid for not recognizing this

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean $||a||-||b||\leq ||a-b||$?

if yes, we have 
$$a=a-b+b$$

Using the triangular inequality, we get

$$||a||=||a-b+b||\leq ||a-b||+||b||$$

Comment: No, it's not that sorry. But I edited my question... can you look at it now?

Comment: It is a similar approach. Please refer  to @Mark comment , there is what you want

Comment: I am not sure you edited it correctly... $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}   x\leq |x|$$
In particular for $x=|a|-|b|$

Answer (score 0):

Try your inequality with $a=1$, $b=-1$.

Comment: Wouldn't that not be a proof because it's just one example?

Comment: If you say "all boxes are white", and I show you a black box, then we know that your assertion was false.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question... can you please look at my question one more time?

Comment: With the current edit, the question is trivial, and it has been answered by Eric.